# Use linq to get date difference in list items

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of appointments, I would like to do a difference between the current appointment start time and last appointment end time to ensure there is no difference. If there is add a fake appointment.

My current implementation is...

```
public ObservableCollection<Appointment> FillGaps()
        {
            var appointments = this.Appointments.OrderByDescending(s => s.EndDate).ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < appointments.Count() - 1; i++)
            {
                var now = appointments[i];

                var previous = appointments[i + 1];

                if((now.StartDate.Value - previous.EndDate.Value).Days > 1)
                {
                    // add a new appointment between this period
                    appointments.Add(new Appointment() 
                          { 
                             StartDate = previous.EndDate.Value.AddDays(1),
                             EndDate = now.StartDate.Value.AddDays(-1), 
                             IsCurrent = false 
                           });
                }
            }

            return appointments.ToObservableCollection();
        }
```

Is there a better or more generic way to do this?

As requested... Adding implementation of ToObservable...

```
 /// <summary>
        /// The to observable collection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="coll">
        /// The collection.
        /// </param>
        /// <typeparam name="T"> Object T
        /// </typeparam>
        /// <returns>
        /// The <see cref="ObservableCollection"/>.
        /// </returns>
        public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> coll)
        {
            var c = new ObservableCollection<T>();
            foreach (var e in coll)
            {
                c.Add(e);
            }

            return c;
        }
```

Nothing special in Appointment class.

```
/// <summary>
    /// The Appointment.
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    public class Appointment
    {
        public Appointment()
        {
            this.IsFake = false;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the start date.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the end date.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the Is Fake
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsFake { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: wouldn't `appointments[i + 1]` throw an IndexOutOfRangeException?

Comment: Spot on, it could. Hence the ask for a better implementation.

Comment: Actually, it wouldn't, the for loop goes to < count -1

Comment: @ShaneA tuche sir! so it does :)

Comment: it's not robust, the start date and end dates are not being checked for has value. They could blast with a null exception too.

Comment: why the check to see if the difference between the start time of `now` and the end time of `previous` is greater than 1 day?

Comment: That's business logic. The difference will be in Days only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing how the `this.Appointments` property is implemented, or what the parameter to the `ToObservableCollection` extension method is, it's difficult to come up with the most effective solution. However, something like this should work:

```
private static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> ListPairs<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
   using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
   {
       if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) yield break;

       T previous = enumerator.Current;
       while (enumerator.MoveNext())
       {
          T current = enumerator.Current;
          yield return new Tuple<T, T>(previous, current);
          previous = current;
       }
   }
}

public ObservableCollection<Appointment> FillGaps()
{
   var gaps = ListPairs(this.Appointments.OrderByDescending(s => s.EndDate))
      .Where(pair => (pair.Item1.StartDate.Value - pair.Item2.EndDate.Value).Days > 1)
      .Select(pair => new Appointment
      {
         StartDate = pair.Item2.EndDate.Value.AddDays(1),
         EndDate = pair.Item1.StartDate.Value.AddDays(-1),
         IsCurrent = false,
      });

   // NB: Assumes "this.Appointments" is a cheap call;
   // Also assumes you don't need the results in any particular order.
   return this.Appointments.Concat(gaps).ToObservableCollection();
}
```

Comment: Why not make it an extension?

Comment: @CSharpie: That would require moving the method to a separate static class, adding argument validation, and adding a pair of methods to ensure that the argument validation was performed eagerly. Somewhat overkill for a simple example of refactoring a single method!